# React: How to render only visible elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I built a component, that gets a json in props, and display it, and the user can edit it, and with a lot of functionality, and looks like this:

[image]

When the user loads a big json, the render time of the component is very slow. So, I want to render only the visible elements, instead all elements in json, so it will be faster. (As you can see, there is a scrollbar when overflow-y).

I saw there are a lot of libraries which support what I want, like `react-window`, or `react-virtualized` etc. The problem is those libraries expect to receive a list of components, like this:

[image]

and in my component, all the components are nested in each other, like json, and very complex with the functionalities.

1) Is there a library which resolve my problem?

2) Is there another solution for the slow render, besides render only the visible elements?

Comment: this library is a custom component for displaying json. I built this kind of component by myself, so i have flexibility with the functionality, so this library does not help me :(   I need someting that will help me display the json fast

Comment: `1) Is there a library which resolve my problem?` Learning to use other people's libraries to solve your problems is a critical part of being a developer.

Comment: Agree with you, but with some certain circumstances , I had to build the component on my own

Comment: Try the library, see if it suffers from the same problems as yours. If it doesn't, read through it's code to find out what it's doing differently. TBH, it's odd that you'll accept a library solution to fix your "slow rendering" but you won't accept a library solution to replace what you built. To be real frank, your component will not have the documentation, stability, flexibility and customizability as rjv. Writing a wrapper around rjv to provide the precise functionality you want can be more rewarding than writing your own rjv from scratch.